# Relative positioned content wrapper not scaling to fit contents

Tags: css, html, css-position

In the following fiddle my expectation is that the element "#wrap" would scale vertically to fit it's contents. This is clearly not the case. Can anyone suggest a simple modification that will cause "#wrap" to automatically scale to fit it's contents (i.e. not with a static height).

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RE9F/6/)

Code:

```
#wrap{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border:5px solid blue;
}

.inner{
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      border:1px solid black;
    left:5px;
}

#id1{
    top:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:green;
}

#id2{
    top:50px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}

#id3{
    top:100px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
}

<div id="wrap">
    <div class="inner" id="id1">hi</div>
    <div class="inner" id="id2"></div>
    <div class="inner" id="id3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `.inner` `div` elements have a `position` of `absolute`, they are taken out of the flow of the page. Thus, any container element no longer sees them (and cannot, therefore, expand to contain them).

What setting the containing `div` element's `position` to `relative` does is allow the absolutely-positioned `.inner` `div` elements to have their `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` properties work off its bounding box rather than the `body` element's bounding box.

If you want them to simply sit on top of each other, then you don't need to position any of elements specially since `block` display elements such as `div` elements always sit on their own lines unless altered by `float` or `position`.

Thus, all you would need to do is get rid of the `position` properties for it to work correctly.

**Updated CSS:**

```
#wrap{
    border:solid blue 5px;
}

#id1{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:green;
}

#id2{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}

#id3{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

I've also removed `display: block;` because `div` elements are displayed as `block` elements by default.

[See JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3RE9F/7/)

If you are trying to achieve something different, then it was not made clear; however, I would be happy to help in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFidle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/3RE9F/1/)

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="inner" id="id1"></div>
    <div class="inner" id="id2"></div>
    <div class="inner" id="id3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

.inner{
      display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

#id1{
    top:0px;
    left:5px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:green;
}

#id2{
    top:0px;
    left:60px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:green;
}

#id3{
    top:0px;
    left:115px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: Sorry Mohsen, my fiddle didn't save properly and you were looking at an old draft. Please see the updated fiddle link.